# How to stop and reset an animation without destroying the original tag object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to reset the animation of an object to it's initial point, so that I can restart it from the beginning.

```js
function swap_animation(node, from, to) {
  let t = node.style.animationDuration;
  node.style.animationDuration = "0s";
  node.style.animationPlayState = "initial";
  setTimeout(function(){
    node.style.animationDuration = t;
    node.classList.remove(from);
    node.classList.add(to);
  }, 10);
}

function grow() {
  let node = document.getElementById("item");
  swap_animation(node, "shrink", "grow");
}

function shrink() {
  let node = document.getElementById("item");
  swap_animation(node, "grow", "shrink");
}
```

```css
.grow {
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 0% 100% 0;
}

.shrink {
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 0% 100% 0;
}

@keyframes title-min
{
  from { transform: scale(0.5); }
  to   { transform: scale(1.0); }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="grow()">Eat me! </button>
  <button onclick="shrink()">Drink me! </button>
  <h1 id="item">Alice </h1>
</body>
```

The sample shows that if you click between <kbd>Eat me!</kbd> and <kbd>Drink me!</kbd>, Alice grows and shrinks in the course of 10 seconds.  However, if you toggle between the two, you will note that the animation is continuing on from where it was before switching.

I think I read somewhere that one way to do this is to clone the object and replace the old one with a new one.  That seems really overkill and I would think could cause performance problems, more so if the object is large, and would also be bad as it can cause memory fragmentation.

There must be some way to keep the object and modify it's properties to fix this, isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I found a answer.  It is to trigger a reflow.  Got the answer from [this site](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/).  Not exactly sure what the `void` is doing there though.

```js
function swap_animation(node, from, to) {
  node.classList.remove(from);
  void node.offsetWidth;
  node.classList.add(to);
}

function grow() {
  let node = document.getElementById("item");
  swap_animation(node, "shrink", "grow");
}

function shrink() {
  let node = document.getElementById("item");
  swap_animation(node, "grow", "shrink");
}
```

```css
.grow {
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 0% 100% 0;
}

.shrink {
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 0% 100% 0;
}

@keyframes title-min
{
  from { transform: scale(0.5); }
  to   { transform: scale(1.0); }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="grow()">Eat me! </button>
  <button onclick="shrink()">Drink me! </button>
  <h1 id="item">Alice </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: The `void` is to ensure your `node.offsetWidth;` getter is actually called, since it could theoretically be mangled by the JIT optimizer (not that I ever seen it happen myself...)